# How to start VirtualBox as UI?

Tags: command-line, server, virtualbox, virtualization

I currently do `startx` which starts openbox and then in the terminal I write `virtualbox` and then start my virtual machine.

Sometimes I don't need the OpenBox environment. I need only the virtual machine GUI.

Is it possible to start it using the `startx` command somehow?

How to start a virtual machine directly, without OpenBox?

I'm using Ubuntu Server.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking but how about `VBoxHeadless -s <Guest-OS-Name>`?

Comment: @Rinzwind Will that start the GUI for the machine?

Comment: Which version of Virtual box and ubuntu?

Comment: @RGG VirtualBox 5.0.24, Ununtu Server 16.04

Comment: @Rinzwind That command doesn't start anything in GUI.

Comment: xclock or any other GUI based app open?

Comment: No, just tty0. It's Ubuntu Server. After I authenticate, I get access to tty0. Then I run `startx` to start the gui session which opens openbox. Is it possible to start a virtual machine directly? How can I do it? Maybe using startx and a script?